# Need to do SSO between IBM Websphere and my custom application

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on, ltpa

I am trying to do an SSO between IBM and my own custom application. Now, from what read I understood is LTPA is a mechanism used by WebSphere and other IBM products (e.g lotus products) as a means of authentication (typically for a Single Sign-on SSO).

Now, can I use this mechanism in my own custom application? What I need is if a person is already logged in IBM Application like Information Governance Catalog so my application should not show its own login page. The user should be automatically logged in

How can I achieve this? In this [Link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_confclltpaauthcoll.html) it is given for older version. I am not very much comfortable in JAVA so please bear with me on this.

Comment: Is your application also deployed on WebSphere (same or separate) or on different server?

Comment: @Gas deployed on same websphere

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying your application on the same WebSphere server, SSO works by default. You dont have to configure anything else. You just need to protect your application (via constraints in `web.xml`) and make sure that 'Application Security' is turned on in WebSphere Global Security configuration. 
Then you should be able to get username via `request.getRemoteUser()`.

The link you provided was for web services, not web applications.

I'm of course assuming that your app is a web app utilizing Java EE security, not some homegrown security solution.